# Framer motion not animating svg correctly with AnimateSharedLayout

Tags: reactjs, svg, framer-motion

I've been playing with the new framer motion library to try to move an svg circle to a new position. It will be from position relative to position fixed so I can't just transform the circle and so was hoping to instead use AnimateSharedLayout.

It is somewhat working but the animation seems to move in a weird path. The animation moves at the right angle but appears like it is coming from outside the svg, rather than it's original position. I have set up an example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-margulis-7ovme

Am I doing something wrong or is this just because AnimateSharedLayout is still in beta? Because it moves at the right angle it feels like it should work, but that maybe I am just missing some other attributes/properties that need to be set so it starts from the right position.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or whether it is just a bug would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised an issue in Framer Motion Github and it does indeed appear to be a bug that they hope to resolve soon.

The bug progress can be tracked here:
https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/605

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AnimateSharedLayout you can do it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={
        active
          ? {
              width: "100px",
              height: "100px",
              backgroundColor: "#000",
              translateX: "300px",
              translateY: "-300px",
              borderRadius: "50%",
            }
          : {
              width: "50px",
              height: "50px",
              backgroundColor: "#000",
              translateX: "0px",
              translateY: "0px",
              borderRadius: "50%",
            }
      }
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't solve my issue. The example I provided was a simplified version of what was required and using an svg and using AnimateSharedLayout would both be requirements

Comment: I don't think AnimateShared Layout can be used for this purpose. As the documentation says: "AnimateSharedLayout allows animation between separate components." So the behavior you are seeing is no bug. It is the default behavior.  What you are trying to do is animate a single component which is something else.

Comment: In my example I am animating between separate components. This is very much the use case for AnimateSharedLayout. Here is an example of it working as expected using divs instead of svgs and using AnimateSharedLayout: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dew-mi9rb. However, for my needs I will need to use svgs as the overall component is more complicated than the example